# Report Reindex taking too long after destroy

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, solr, report, sunspot-solr

I have an product report that lists all products registered.
When i destroy(delete) one of items from de product list i need the item to be removed from the report list.
I do use Sunspot Solr with Mysql.
I tried the following way:

```
after_destroy { ProductsReport.reindex; Sunspot.commit }
```

But because of my gigantic list of products it takes too long to execute.
Is that a simple or more performing way to do it?

By the way, my system is built in Ruby on Rails.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe you can use a background job for that. Have a look at: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html

Comment: I already use a job that does it every day in the dawn, but when the users are updating their product list and their product stock control, they complain about the product is not being removed instantly from de report.
A full reindex every time is high costly and slow... so im searching for ways to delete the part of the index that belongs to the deleted data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The previous answer is correct - instead of reindexing, you should only remove the document in question from Solr, There is no need to reindex *all the documents* if only one document has changed.

In Sunspot you do can do this [with `Sunspot.remove(Doc)`](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/sunspot/Sunspot.remove).

Comment: Thanks for the help, will take a look on this article.

Answer (score 1):

You may very well be able to optimize this operation, but the details of how to do it depend on your data model and your Solr setup. I also question whether a full reindex is needed on each delete. Can you just delete the Solr document for the deleted record?

Regardless, I recommend updating your search cluster asynchronously using a queueing service. Popular options for Rails apps include [DelayedJob](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job) and [Resque](https://github.com/resque/resque).

Comment: A reindex is being costly to me, so its possible to delete only the part of the index registry that belongs to this product ?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with Solr but a little Googling suggests that it's possible.